# Как обработать конец анимации с помощью arch.lifecycle?

Tags: android

В моем приложении есть фрагмент. Внутри фрагмента кастомная вью, в которой реализована анимация на основе ValueAnimator. Когда анимация заканчивается, фрагмент об этом уведомляется с помощью колбэка.

Проблема заключается в том, что пользователь может свернуть окно во время анимации. В результате, колбэк вызывается в неактивном фрагменте, что приводит к различного рода проблемам.

Кажется, что новые возможности из arch.lifecycle как раз призваны помочь в таких ситуациях. Но как их применить в моем случае?